# Google Datastore (NoSQL) backend for PHP CMS

Tags: nosql, gae-datastore

I am working on a personal project where I am creating a small CMS using PHP as the developing language, but I want to be able to deploy it to the Google App Engine and I want to use its Google Datastore (NoSQL).

The question I have is how to do relationship between kinds?

**For example:**

- Kind 1: call category
- Kind 2: call tags
- Kind 3: call post

I want the posts to be able to have one category, but multiple tags. I am having trouble visualizing it. I am coming from SQL world so having the ID of the category and the IDs of the tags to them JOIN them will take care of the same issue.

**Note:** if there is some tutorial or reading that you could share I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/storage . This should get you started on the use and main concepts.
FYI joins are not applicable to the datastore but if you model out your data correctly you should have no problem.

Comment: Best to paraphrase and answer from a link or include the relevant text rather than just posting the link as the answer.  see http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100/are-there-any-regulations-on-right-answers-that-just-contain-links/101#101

Comment: I really didn't get any question from the text above. I just got he was las looking for guidance on how to get started

Comment: Hi @jirungaray thank you for your answer and comment. Google Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Storage are available thru PHP in the Google App Engine, but officially the App Engine Datastore is not. Google has provided an API and a workaround to access it and that is what I am using.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more or provide a sample to the modeling of the data in the App Engine Datastore? Once again thank you.